# C# To transform Facebook Response to proper encoded string

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, encoding, utf-8

I am using regular Stream Reader to get response from Facebook graph API response 
https://graph.facebook.com/XXXX?access_token=&fields=id,name,about,address,last_name

I am reading the response stream yet it returns me
{"id":"XXXXX","name":"K\u0131r\u0131nt\u0131 Reklam"...}

My code is below - I unsuccessfully tried using explicitly UTF-8 and "iso-8859-9" (Turkish) encodings and setting accept-charset headers. I read Joel's famous article about encodings. It looks like each of the chars '\' 'u' '1' '3' '1' are coming as characters from facebook - I thought this would have been 2 bytes for value 131 in UTF-8. I am confused. I expect this string to be "Kırıntı Reklam".

I could simply find/replace those strings - yet it would be far from elegant and maintainable. How should I properly process or convert the facebook graph api response for strings with accents?

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (dataStream != null)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
        {
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Working solution to decode the text before parsing it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50803989/396337)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*tldr;* use a JSON library - I like [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) - and don't worry about it.

The JSON shown is *valid* [JSON](http://json.org) where `\uABCD` in a *JSON string* represents a UTF-16 encoded character<sup>1</sup>. The internal JSON character escaping format is useful to *avoid* having to deal with Unicode *stream* encoding issues - it allows JSON to be represented entirely in ASCII/7-bit-clean characters (which is a subset of UTF-8).

Using a conforming JSON library to parse the JSON with such escapes would restore the JSON into an appropriate object-graph, of which some values will be properly-decoded *String values*. The library is responsible for understanding JSON and converting/reading it as appropriate - this includes correctly handling any such `\u` escape sequences.

The *stream* itself (that of the *JSON text*) should use the encoding that the server says, is indicated by a BOM, or has been pre-negotiated: but really, just UTF-8 here. This is how the *JSON text* is encoded, but has no bearing on the escape sequences found in JSON strings.

---

<sup>1</sup> Per [RFC 4627, The application/json Media Type for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> **Any character may be escaped.**  If the character is in the Basic
> Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be
> represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed
> by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that
> encode the character's code point.  The hexadecimal letters A though
> F can be upper or lowercase.  So, for example, a string containing
> only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as
> `"\u005C"`.

> Alternatively, there are two-character sequence escape
> representations of some popular characters.  So, for example, a
> string containing only a single reverse solidus character may be
> represented more compactly as `"\\"`.

> To escape an extended character that is not in the Basic Multilingual
> Plane, the character is represented as a twelve-character sequence,
> encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair.  So, for example, a string
> containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as
> `"\uD834\uDD1E"`

---

For the doubters, here is a LINQPad example. This uses JSON.Net and imports the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq namespace.

```
var json = @"{""name"":""K\u0131r\u0131nt\u0131 Reklam""}";
json.Dump();                        // -> {"name":"K\u0131r\u0131nt\u0131 Reklam"}
var name = JObject.Parse(json)["name"].ToString();
(name == "Kırıntı Reklam").Dump();  // -> true
```

Comment: The faceboook encoding is dead wrong, everyone complain about it, Json.Net library doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @Zyo People complaining about valid things, even if such are not expected, does not make the valid things "dead wrong". I've updated the answer the a demonstration snippet that can be run in LINQPad. JSON.Net understands/accepts such *valid and well-defined JSON*, and thus correctly deserializes the value. Ensure to use JSON-aware libraries/tools with JSON data.