# "<" character in JSON data is serialized to \u003c

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization, encoding, javascriptserializer

I have a JSON object where the value of one element is a string.  In this string there are the characters `"<RPC>"`.  I take this entire JSON object and in my ASP.NET server code, I perform the following to take the object named `rpc_response` and add it to the data in a POST response:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"files.json\"");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(rpc_response));
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
```

After the object is serialized, I receive it on the other end (not a web browser), and that particular string looks like: `\u003cRPC\u003e`.

What can I do to prevent these (and other) characters from not being encoded properly, still being able to serialize my JSON object?

Answer (score 12):

The characters *are* being encoded "properly"!<sup>1</sup> Use a working *JSON library* to correctly access the JSON data - it is a *valid* [JSON](http://json.org) encoding.

Escaping these characters *prevents HTML injection via JSON* - and makes the JSON XML-friendly. That is, even if the JSON is emited directly into JavaScript (as is done fairly often as JSON is a valid<sup>2</sup> subset of JavaScript), it cannot be used to terminate the `<script>` element early because the relevant characters (e.g. `<`, `>`) are encoded within JSON itself.

The standard [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) does *not* have the ability to change this behavior. Such escaping *might* be configurable (or different) in the [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) implementation - but, it *shouldn't matter* because a valid JSON client/library *must* understand the `\u` escapes.

---

<sup>1</sup> From [RFC 4627: The application/json Media Type for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt),

> **Any character may be escaped.** If the character is in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that encode the character's code point ..

See also [C# To transform Facebook Response to proper encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495454/c-sharp-to-transform-facebook-response-to-proper-encoded-string/21495472#21495472) (which is also related to the JSON escaping).

<sup>2</sup> There is [a rare case when this does not hold](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset), but ignoring (or accounting for) that..

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem. I liked how the JavaScripSerializer escapes < and > but when I switch to Json.NET it doesn't escape those characters causing errors when I inject Json in my page and browser gets confused when it sees ```</script>``` in my json strings. Any way to induce Json.NET to escape properly?