# Rails, why '.to_json' is escaping html entities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, escaping

This is what happens in a `rails console` (Rails v4.0.4):

```
irb(main):020:0> "pepe&pepe <juan>".to_json
=> "\"pepe\\u0026pepe \\u003Cjuan\\u003E\""
```

This is what happens in a `irb console` (Ruby 2.0.0p247):

```
irb(main):014:0> "pepe&pepe <juan>".to_json
=> "\"pepe&pepe <juan>\""
```

I know I can override this behaviour but my concern is **why Rails is doing this by default**? which can be the consequences of not doing it?, because for me it looks like a good idea to override this behaviour and not escaping html entities but I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is written to HTML contexts - scripts and attributes - *a lot* in Rails.

This default escaping *avoids* injection in such cases:  *characters that have meaning in a particular context and are not escaped pose an injection / XSS risk.*<sup>1</sup>

If, and only if, dealing in a context where such is not the case then it can be safely disabled: *the default is simply to favor 'safety'.* Since this HTML-safe transformation can be done *without* breaking any standard and *without* chaining the JSON-equivalency<sup>2</sup> it is what the Rail's ream has done - good for them!<sup>3</sup>

In particular this avoids nasty 'JSON'<sup>2</sup> like:

```
var x = {"foo": "</script><script>alert('owned')</script>"};
```

JSON embedded into other HTML constructs, eg. data-attributes, can also be problematic. Even using `JSON.parse`, which would require an extra encoding step, leaves the same potential issue.

---

<sup>1</sup> The standard safe-encoded output methods apply to HTML PCDATA contexts, but in the case of emitting JSON to a script element (CDATA) this is not desirable and purposefully skipped (eg. with `raw`).

<sup>2</sup> Here is [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592283/character-in-json-data-is-serialized-to-u003c/21592423#21592423) where I wrote about about why such escaping is *always valid* as well as a caveat of using JSON as a JavaScript Literal. Unlike the notorious and ill-devised 'add slashes', the HTML-safe JSON represents identical information.

<sup>3</sup> JavaScriptSerializer from Microsoft and json_encode in PHP has similar default encoding behavior. The default context in which these libraries/functions are used probably plays a large factor on the default HTML-safe configurations.

Comment: I really appreciate and accept the extended answer you have offered. But I can't agree with the arrogance of Rails on this regard. This `.to_json` overwriting was adding issues to a general library that is loaded in the same context of a Rails application. The Rails application decides that the standard Ruby way of parsing objects to _json_ now is gonna change and so it is changing to any library is loaded with Rails :/. I accept overwriting standard methods is good idea and very helpful but I think the original behaviour must to remain as default.

Comment: @fguillen JavaScriptSerializer from Microsoft and json_encode from PHP both follow a similar HTML-safe default encoding. Sine the encoded JSON is equivalent - but not text content equal, *which was never guaranteed* - I don't have a problem with the transformation. In any case, such concerns will be better directed to the appropriate project home / mailing list.

Comment: @fguillen: But `"\u003C"` *is* `"<"` in both JSON and JavaScript. No compliant JSON decoder should care about the difference because there really isn't any difference. Yes, Rails tends to be arrogant, pig-headed, and opinionated but they're really not be that bad this time, they're still producing fully compliant JSON.