# How to avoid useless special characters encoding?

Tags: json, powershell, encoding

In a PowerShell script, I have some custom data structure that contains Xml in string properties.

When I convert my data structure, useless encoding make the result difficult to read and write (json file used by my script may be manually adapted to match customer requirements before use).

Ex:

```
"<" | ConvertTo-Json
```

Returns :

```
"\u003c"
```

As far as I know, the `<` is perfectly valid within a json string.

1. Why `Convertto-Json` encode these character ?
2. Is there a way to avoid it ?

As a comparison, this code:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Newtonsoft.Json")
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeObject("<")
```

outputs:

```
"<"
```

But this solution relies on a 3rd party library and requires to ship it with my script (which are intended to be distributed to various customer environments).

Comment: Why is "\u003c" not usable for you?

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json` uses the [`JavaScriptDeserializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class. As microsoft is not popular for making good decisions at browser technologies... Well, there might be your reason for that mess ;)

Comment: @ArcSet: actually, it works as expected. The `ConvertFrom-Json` can read these caracters. However, the files may be manually tweaked before use... having this unicode mess make it very difficult to manipulate.

Comment: Why not do this?
 `"<>"| ConvertTo-Json | %{ $_.replace("\u003c","<").replace("\u003e",">")}`

Comment: see... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959431/json-file-to-powershell-and-back-to-json-file