# Powershell JSON transformation removing unicode escape chars without removing literal \n

Tags: regex, powershell, azure-rm-template, azure-data-factory

My issue us similiar to this question:

[Json file to powershell and back to json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959431/json-file-to-powershell-and-back-to-json-file)

When importing and exporting ARM templates in powershell, using `Convert-FromJson` and `Convert-ToJson`, introduces unicode escape sequences.

I used the code [here](https://www.cryingcloud.com/blog/2017/05/02/replacefix-unicode-characters-created-by-convertto-json-in-powershell-for-arm-templates) to unescape again.

Some example code (mutltiline for clarity):

```
$armADF = Get-Content -Path $armFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$armADFString = $armADF | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 50
$armADFString | 
    ForEach-Object { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } | 
    Out-File $outputFile
```

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=netframework-4.8) the doco I've been reading for `Unescape`

Results in the the output file being identical *except* that all instances of literal `\n` (that were in the original JSON file) are turned into actual carriage returns. Which breaks the ARM template.

If I don't include the Unescape code, the `\n` are preserved but so are the unicode characters which also breaks the ARM template.

It seems like I need to pre-escape the `\n` so when I call Unescape they are turned into nice little `\n`. I've tried a couple of things like adding this before calling unescape.

```
$armADFString = $armADFString -replace("\\n","\u000A")
```

Which does not give me the results I need.

Anyone come across this and solved it? Any accomplished escape artists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reread the Unescape doco and noticed that it would also basically remove leading `\` characters so I tried this unlikely bit of code:

```
$armADF = Get-Content -Path $armFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$armADFString = $armADF | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 50
$armADFString = $armADFString -replace("\\n","\\n")
$armADFString | 
    ForEach-Object { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } | 
    Out-File $outputFile
```

Of course - replacing `\\n` with `\\n` makes complete sense :|

More than happy for anyone to pose a more elegant solution.

EDIT: I am deploying ADF ARM templates which are themselves JSON based. TO cut a long story short I also found I needed to add this to stop it unescaping legitimately escaped quotes:

```
$armADFString = $armADFString -replace('\\"','\\"')
```

Comment: Well, knowing the RegEx based `-replace` operator needs escaping on the ***matching*** part only, it does make sense (+1 ;-)

Comment: Yep fair comment.