# Access key Value pairs of a blob json in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I have a JSON , like so(posting just the initial snippet) :

```
[
  {
    "ICloudBlob":      {
      "StreamWriteSizeInBytes":  4194304,
      "ServiceClient":  {
        "AuthenticationScheme":  1,
        "BufferManager":  null,
        "Credentials":      {
          "SASToken":  null,
          "AccountName":
          "storageaccountappse9a4d",
          "KeyName":  null,
          "IsAnonymous":  false,
          "IsSAS":  false,
          "IsSharedKey":  true,
          "IsToken":  false,
          "SASSignature":  null
        },
        "BaseUri":
        "https://storageaccountappse9a4d.blob.core.windows.net/",
        "StorageUri":  {
          "PrimaryUri":
          "https://storageaccountappse9a4d.blob.core.windows.net/",
          "SecondaryUri":  null
        },
        "DefaultRequestOptions":  {
          "RetryPolicy":  {

          },
          "EncryptionPolicy":  null,
          "RequireEncryption":  null,
          "CustomerProvidedKey":  null,
          "EncryptionScope":  null,
          "AbsorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry":  null,
          "LocationMode":  0,
          "ServerTimeout":  null,
          "MaximumExecutionTime":  null,
          "NetworkTimeout":  null,
          "ParallelOperationThreadCount":  1,
          "SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes":  134217728,
          "UseTransactionalMD5":  null,
          "StoreBlobContentMD5":  null,
          "DisableContentMD5Validation":  null,
          "ChecksumOptions":  {
            "DisableContentMD5Validation":  null,
            "StoreContentMD5":  null,
            "UseTransactionalMD5":  null,
            "DisableContentCRC64Validation":  null,
            "UseTransactionalCRC64":  null
          }
```

I want to access the ***ParallelOperationThreadCount*** parameter, for which i'm using the following code:

```
$JSON_obj=Get-AzStorageAccount | Get-AzStorageContainer | Get-AzStorageBlob | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 
50
$ParallelOperationThreadCount=@()
foreach($i in $JSON_obj)
{
$ParallelOperationThreadCount+=$i.ICloudBlob.ServiceClient.DefaultRequestOptions.ParallelOperationThreadCount

 }
$ParallelOperationThreadCount
```

However,on running this,no output comes out. It runs and then exits.
Any way to figure out what might work ?

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: using VSCode.And have mentioned the code snippet in the question.

Comment: If you do `ConvertTo-JSON`, you converting your `object` to a (JSON)  `string`. If you want to convert a (JSON) `string` to an `object`, you should use: [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)

Comment: I also wouldn't call your variable `$JSON_obj`, as that is confusing, it is just an object and has no longer a relation with Json (after you do a `ConvertFrom-Json`). Meaning, you can't iterate through a Json string, you're iterating through an object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cmdlet `ConvertTo-JSON` will convert your results to json string. It will not return the result as an array.
[image]

So I suggest you remove the cmdlet `ConvertTo-JSON` in the first line command. After doing that, the command return the result as object array. Then your script will return the right results.
[image]

For example (I do that in one storage account)

```
Connect-AzAccount

$accountName =""
$groupName=""

$JSON_obj=(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $groupName -Name $accountName  | Get-AzStorageContainer  | Get-AzStorageBlob )

$ParallelOperationThreadCount=@()
foreach($i in $JSON_obj)
{
$ParallelOperationThreadCount+=$i.ICloudBlob.ServiceClient.DefaultRequestOptions.ParallelOperationThreadCount

 }
$ParallelOperationThreadCount
```

[image]

Besides, we also can simplify the script as below.

```
$ParallelOperationThreadCount= (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $groupName -Name $accountName  |
        Get-AzStorageContainer  | Get-AzStorageBlob|
        Select-Object -Property @{Name="ParallelOperationThreadCount";Expression={$_.ICloudBlob.ServiceClient.DefaultRequestOptions.ParallelOperationThreadCount}})

$ParallelOperationThreadCount
```

[image]

---

### Update

Please refer to the following script

```
Connect-AzAccount

$accountName =""
$groupName=""

$JSON_obj=(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $groupName -Name $accountName  | Get-AzStorageContainer  | Get-AzStorageBlob )

$ParallelOperationThreadCount=@()
foreach($i in $JSON_obj)
{
$ParallelOperationThreadCount+=$i.ICloudBlob.ServiceClient.DefaultRequestOptions.ParallelOperationThreadCount

 }
$ParallelOperationThreadCount

$JSON_obj|ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 50 | % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } | Out-File -Encoding Ascii - append C:\Users\rakshitas\Documents\json_excel\blob.json
```

Comment: so this works,thanks. I wanna store the json in a file as well,and it needs some changes hence using this command:
    $JSON=Get-AzStorageAccount | Get-AzStorageContainer | Get-AzStorageBlob | 
    ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 50 | % { 
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } | Out-File -Encoding Ascii - 
   append C:\Users\rakshitas\Documents\json_excel\blob.json
    $JSON_obj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $JSON.                                                     It doesn't work then,any suggestions ?

Comment: This helps. There's another key value pair I wanted to access , it has a \u0027 unicode.The script I mentioned returns the json that way. But , doesn't return any output when I access feilds like now. Think it may be because of this code here : -Depth 50 | % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } ?

Comment: @Rakshita  Please try to use `$JSON_obj|ConvertTo-JSON|Out-File`.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I get in the outfile. Few entries with unicode with them. The regex code , removes them. But then I ain't able to access key-value pairs. You think it may be because of these specific line of code?

Comment: @Rakshita please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959431/json-file-to-powershell-and-back-to-json-file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230805/discussion-between-rakshita-and-jim-xu).